# Nokogiri: how to display partial output of the css selector?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

Say that I am pulling the address from `div.body h3 a`. The issue is, what if I only wanted part of the address? For example, if the html read: `<a href="/usa/sale/100-happy-street">100 Happy Street #PH </a>`

How do I say, I only want to display the `PH`?

Comment: But how do I know to only show anything like #PH and ignore the rest?

Comment: Can you define precisely what "anything like #PH" means? If so, then you can express it as a regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
anchor = doc.at('div.body h3 a') # the <a …>…</a> element
link   = anchor.text             # "100 Happy Street #PH "
last   = link[ /#([^#]+)/, 1 ]      # "PH"
```

This regex (which has nothing to do with Ruby on Rails or Nokogiri) extracts all text from a string that comes after the last `#` in the string, assuming that there is at least one `#`. You could get a similar result with `last = link.split("#").last`.